# Eclipse CDT C++ RDT remote fast indexer for AIX not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am developing C++ code for AIX 6.1, and using eclipse CDT and RDT plugin to load the project on windows and edit it. But I am not able to index the code using `RDT remote fast indexer`. 
Have started `daemon.pl` script on AIX on default port. 
I have enabled Code indexing in `Service configuration` property in Remote Development tab of eclipse preferences. I have not found much help on google too. I keep getting errors of
`java not found` or `An internal error occurred during: "Open Declaration".
java.lang.NullPointerException` .
Has anyone faced similar issues on AIX? Please help.
Also havent been able to compile my remote project(using xlC compiler) or debug, which RDT promises to.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108951

-> Increase cache limits of indexer (in workspace's preferences or project's properties).
-> Then rebuild index